# Image uploading in Flask blog with CKeditor 5

Tags: python, flask, ckeditor

I'm stuck with following problem while creating my Flask based blog.

Firstly, I used CKeditor 4 but than upgraded to 5 version.

I can't understand how to handle image upload on server side now, with adapters etc. As for 4 version, I used flask-ckeditor extension and Flask documentation to handle image uploading.

I didn't find any examples for this combination. I understand that I lack knowledge and I'm looking for advice in which direction may I advance and which concepts should I know to approach such subject.

Thanks in advance.

My takes on this so far:

According to https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/simple-upload-adapter.html
(official guide on simplest adapters).
`config.simpleUpload.uploadUrl` should be like `/upload` route that was used in cke4. Object with URL property needed by cke5 is cke4's `upload_successful` which was returned by /upload route.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured it out.

As for cke 4:
`/upload` route handled uploading process by returning `upload_successful()` from flask-ckeditor extension.
`upload_successful()` itself is a jsonify-ing function, which in turn modify arguments to fit json format.

As for cke 5:
There were some things aside upload handling, which caused problems.

1. Plugin used: ["Simple upload adapter"](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/simple-upload-adapter.html)

   - I integrated cke5 by downloading from [Online-builder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/) and then reinstalling and rebuilding it by myself. (for this on Ubuntu 20.04 I installed `nodejs` and `npm` by `sudo apt install`.) Plugin is installed by executing from `/static/ckeditor` folder:

     `npm install`

     `npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload`

     `npm run build` (need to wait here for a little)
   - Different adapters may conflict and not allow Editor to load, so I removed CKFinder adapter from `src/ckeditor.js` in `import` and `.builtinPlugins` sections, replacing them by `import SimpleUploadAdapter from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload/src/adapters/simpleuploadadapter.js';`  and `SimpleUploadAdapter`  correspondingly.
2. `.html`, where CKEditor instance is created. `body` here is name of `flask_wtf` text-field:

   ```html
   <script>
       ClassicEditor
           .create( document.querySelector( '#body' ), {
               extraPlugins: ['SimpleUploadAdapter'],
               simpleUpload: {
                   uploadUrl: '/upload',
               },
               mediaEmbed: {previewsInData: true}
           } )
           .catch( error => {
               console.error( error.stack );
           } );
   </script>
   ```
3. Things to notice:

   - In official [guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/installing-plugins.html) plugins are recommended to enable as following:

```html
.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        plugins: [ Essentials, Paragraph, Bold, Italic, Alignment ],
```

- For me it is not working: Editor would not load with such syntaxis. What worked is this (from [docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editorconfig-EditorConfig.html#member-plugins)):

```html
.create( document.querySelector( '#body' ), {
            extraPlugins: ['SimpleUploadAdapter'],
```

So, `plugins` -> `extraPlugins` and `PluginName` -> `'PluginName'`.

4. `/upload` route itself:

```js
@main.route('/files/<path:filename>')
def uploaded_files(filename):
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    path = app.config['UPLOADED_PATH']
    return send_from_directory(path, filename)
    
@main.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    f = request.files.get('upload')
    # Add more validations here
    extension = f.filename.split('.')[-1].lower()
    if extension not in ['jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'jpeg']:
        return upload_fail(message='Image only!')
    f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOADED_PATH'], f.filename))
    url = url_for('main.uploaded_files', filename=f.filename)
    return jsonify(url=url)
```

I will edit this answer as I advance in this subject.